# INNER JOIN com conflito de colunas iguais

Tags: php

Neste `SELECT JOIN`, todas as tabelas tem colunas com mesmo nome.
Com isso, dá um conflito na hora de listar.

Exemplo: coluna `Id_saida` ele está em todas as tabelas. Como listar cada uma delas?

```
$cmd = "SELECT f.*,a.*,e.*,p.*,m.*,v.* FROM a_finan AS f

       INNER JOIN agenda_saidas AS a
       ON a.id_saida    = f.id_saida

       LEFT JOIN empresas AS e
       ON e.id_empresa  = f.id_empresa

       LEFT JOIN passageiros AS p
       ON p.id_saida    = f.id_saida

       LEFT JOIN motoristas AS m
       ON m.id    = a.id_motorista

       LEFT JOIN veiculos AS v
       ON v.id_veiculo    = a.id_veiculo


       where a.id_transfer1 = '$id_transfer'  AND f.id_transfer =  
       '$id_transfer' 
       AND e.id_transfer  = '$id_transfer'  
       AND a.start BETWEEN '$de' AND '$ate' 
       ";

    $produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
    $total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {

     $id_saida = $linha['id_saida'];  // Coluna id_saida em todas as tabelas
     $id_saida = $linha['id_saida'];  // tabela 2
     $id_saida = $linha['id_saida'];  // tabela 3
     }
```

Comment: O ideal é sempre selecionar apenas as colunas que você precisa ao invés de usar o *, e nesse caso acaba sendo inevitável, pois você tem que adicionar apelidos para cada coluna repetida(conforme resposta do Silvio Andorinha) para poder resgatá-los via php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atribua o valor do campo a uma referencia por exemplo, no select use

```
SELECT p.id_saida as id_saidaTabelap, p.id_saida as id_saidaTabelaf
```

e quando você for pegar o valor la faça

```
$id_saidaP = $linha['id_saidaTabelap'];  // tabela 2
$id_saidaF = $linha['id_saidaTabelaf'];  // tabela 3
```